# Using Pandas dataframe to process list data get loc error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to process List data. The list data is

```
[(datetime.date(1992, 2, 1), 114535.0), (datetime.date(1992, 3, 1), 120025.0), (datetime.date(1992, 4, 1), 124470.0), (datetime.date(1992, 5, 1), 125822.0), (datetime.date(1992, 6, 1), 122834.0)]
```

I create labels and use DataFrame.from_records to read the data

```
labels = ['date', 'value']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listData, columns=labels)

df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.loc['1992-03-01'])
```

I got the following error using `df.loc`

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '1992-03-01'
```

Comment: You have `datetime` objects in a `pd.Index` index, so you have to access the index with `datetime` - df.loc[datetime.date(1992,3,1)]. You could use strings directly if you had `pd.DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert `dates objects` to `timestamp`s:

```
labels = ['date', 'value']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listData, columns=labels)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.loc['1992-03-01'])
value    120025.0
Name: 1992-03-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Or looking by date objects:

```
labels = ['date', 'value']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listData, columns=labels)

df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.loc[datetime.date(1992, 3, 1)])
value    120025.0
Name: 1992-03-01, dtype: float64
```